# PHP does not print anything after Doctrine's entity manager has flushed

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine

I am following the "Getting Started with Doctrine" simple, short tutorial
([here](http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/tutorials/getting-started.html) )

I am encountering a problem with the `create_product.php` file. Here
is my own `create_product.php file`, it has a few lines of code
added to the original for debugging purposes :

```
<?php
// create_product.php

require_once "bootstrap.php";
require_once "src/Product.php";

$newProductName = $argv[1];

$product = new Product();
$product->setName($newProductName);

var_dump($product);

echo "Step 1 done\n";

$entityManager->persist($product);

echo "Step 2 done\n";

$entityManager->flush();

echo "Step 3 done\n";

echo "Created Product with ID " . $product->getId() . "\n";
```

When I try `php create_product.php Alice` in my terminal,
I get the following output :

```
ewandelanoy$ php create_product.php Alice
class Product#22 (2) {
  protected $id =>
  NULL
  protected $name =>
  string(5) "Alice"
}
Step 1 done
Step 2 done
ewandelanoy$
```

As you can see, nothing is printed after the "flush" step,
and indeed my database has not been updated.

What did I do wrong ? Any help appreciated.

Comment: did you check log files? apparently something wrong is happening inside ``flush``

Comment: @TomaszMadeyski where are those log files ? there is no filename ending with "log" in my project directory

Comment: in ``app/logs`` directory (files ``dev.log`` and ``prod.log`` should be there)

Comment: @TomaszMadeyski As I followed the tutorial to the letter, I only installed a minimal part of symfony in my project, so I have no `app/` directory. I'll see if I can somewhat rework the tutorial to do it on a full symfony installation, but I don't like doing things like this because of the risk of other problems adding to the initial problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you are not in a Symfony project and have no error logs, you have to set the error logging. In your php file, you can add the following on top of your file :

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
```

See [php error_reporting](http://php.net/manual/fr/function.error-reporting.php)

Or, make something like :

```
try {
    $entityManager->flush();
} catch (\Exception $e) {
    print $e->getMessage();
}
```

To catch the exception during the flush, if there is an exception.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. It seems that no exception is thrown, because adding `error_reporting(E_ALL);` changes nothing to the output.

Comment: Maybe move the `flush` into a try/catch (like I suggest as second) will print an error.

Comment: You are right, when I do the try/catch thing I get the error message `An exception occurred while executing 'INSERT INTO products (name) VALUES (?)' with params ["Alice"]:Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'flea_database.products' doesn't exist` even though Doctrine told me just before it had created it successfully. My original problem has morphed into something rather different, so I'll accept this answer and ask a second question